# I've been given an assignment on destructuring, can someone help me understand how to destructure object { } nested within an array [ ]?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was given this code and was asked to output an HTML table, but I can't I haven't grasped the full understanding of destructuring. Here it looks like I was given objects nested within an array named "people", nested within an object named 'userList'.

I've tried giving the inner objects names or variables because I don't know to destructure multiple object with out a variable assignment. Geez I'm struggling...

```js
      var userList = {
        "people": [

          { firstName: "Fred",
            lastName: "Smith",
            dateOfBirth: 1980,
            spokenLanguages: {
              native: "English",
              fluent: "Spanish",
              intermediate: "Chinese" }
          },
          
          { firstName: "Monica",
            lastName: "Taylor",
            dateOfBirth: 1975,
            spokenLanguages: {
              native: "Spanish",
              fluent: "English",
              intermediate: "French" }
          },

          { firstName: "Maurice",
            lastName: "Edelson",
            dateOfBirth: 1992,
            spokenLanguages: {
              native: "English",
              fluent: "Spanish", }
          },

          { firstName: "Kelly",
            lastName: "Lang",
            dateOfBirth: 1982,
              spokenLanguages: {
              native: "English",
              fluent: "German",
              intermediate: "Dutch" }
          }
        ]
      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object/Array destructuring is simply a syntax that allows for property/index access of an Object or an Array.

**Example of Object destructuring to access a property:**

```js
var user = {
  name: "fred"
};

var { userName } = user;
```

In the above example, the variable `userName` now holds the value `"fred"`.

This is equivelant to accessing the same value via property chains. To access the `name` property from the `user` Object using property chaining, you would simply do `var username = user.name;`.

**Example of Array destructuring to access the value at a specific index index:**

```js
var users = [
  {
    name: "fred"
  },
  {
    name: "joe"
  }
];

var [userOne] = users;
// ^-- userOne now holds the object at index `users[0]`
```

In the above example, the variable `userOne` now holds the value that was held in the first index of the variable `users`, which was an Array of two objects.

Destructuring an Array in this way is equivelant to accessing an index of an array using the more traditional syntax: `var userOne = users[0];`.

By accessing the first index (index `0`) of the users array with the syntax `var userOne = users[0]`, we are assigning the value of that index to the `userOne` variable.

To apply these concepts to your specific example, you would be able to destructure the `userList` object as so:

```js
var userList = {
  people: [
    {
      firstName: "Fred",
      lastName: "Smith",
      dateOfBirth: 1980,
      spokenLanguages:
      {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "Spanish",
        intermediate: "Chinese"
      }
    },
    {
      firstName: "Monica",
      lastName: "Taylor",
      dateOfBirth: 1975,
      spokenLanguages:
      {
        native: "Spanish",
        fluent: "English",
        intermediate: "French"
      }
    }
  ]
};

// Assign the value of `userList.people (Array)` to the variable `people`
var { people } = userList;

// Iterate each 'person' in the `people` Array
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

  var person = people[i];

  /**
   * Assign the property values of the temporary variable `person` to
   * the variables `firstName`, `lastName`, `dateOfBirth`, and `spokenLanguages`.
   */
  var { firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, spokenLanguages } = person;

  /**
   * Assign the property values of the variable `spokenLanguages` to the variables
   * `native`, `fluent`, and `intermediate`. 
   */
  var { native, fluent, intermediate } = spokenLanguages;

  console.log(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, native, fluent, intermediate);
}
```

From the above example, you should be able to work with the variables and use their values to construct a table or perform other operations with the data.

Comment: to add to this answer, `var { userName } = user;` will let you use the variable `userName` and it's value; but if you want to change the value of `userName` itself and do `userName = "something else"`, it will not affect the actual object `user`. If you do `const { userName } = user;` (ie, `const` instead of `var`), you won't be able to reassign a new value to `userName` at all.

Comment: If you can avoid using external demo tools, please do so. Stack Overflow’s snippet editor not only makes copy/pasting easier, but helps to ensure examples and demos will still be available years from now.

Comment: @vol7ron "helps to ensure examples and demos will still be available years from now.", that's fair, have updated to prefer the SO snippet.

Comment: It’s not a requirement, just helpful. The mobile apps (iOS) still don’t support that feature and they still have limitations compared to the plethora of alternatives.  It’s not mandatory, just encouraged where suitable.

Answer (score 0):

There's two places where it might make sense to the destructure; first, with the object and then with each object's properties.

The object:

```
let { people } = userList;
```

The properties:

```
// Iterate and destructure the properties
people.forEach( ({ firstName, lastName }) => console.log(firstName, lastName) );
```

---

#### Example

```js
var userList = getData();

// Destructure the object
let { people } = userList;

// Iterate and destructure the properties
people.forEach(({ firstName, lastName }) => console.log(firstName, lastName));


function getData() {
  return {
    "people": [

      {
        firstName: "Fred",
        lastName: "Smith",
        dateOfBirth: 1980,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "English",
          fluent: "Spanish",
          intermediate: "Chinese"
        }
      },

      {
        firstName: "Monica",
        lastName: "Taylor",
        dateOfBirth: 1975,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "Spanish",
          fluent: "English",
          intermediate: "French"
        }
      },

      {
        firstName: "Maurice",
        lastName: "Edelson",
        dateOfBirth: 1992,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "English",
          fluent: "Spanish",
        }
      },

      {
        firstName: "Kelly",
        lastName: "Lang",
        dateOfBirth: 1982,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "English",
          fluent: "German",
          intermediate: "Dutch"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### HTML Table

```js
init()

function init(){
  var userList = getData();
  let { people } = userList; 
  const app = document.querySelector('#app');

  let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
  // Table
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  fragment.appendChild(table);
  
  // Tbody
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  table.appendChild(tbody);

  // Rows + Data
  let body = people.map(({ firstName, lastName }) =>`
    <tr>
      <td>${firstName}</td>
      <td>${lastName}</td>
    </tr>
  `);

  tbody.innerHTML = body.join('');  // insert data

  // Bind Table to DOM
  app.appendChild(fragment);
}

function getData() {
  return {
    "people": [

      {
        firstName: "Fred",
        lastName: "Smith",
        dateOfBirth: 1980,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "English",
          fluent: "Spanish",
          intermediate: "Chinese"
        }
      },

      {
        firstName: "Monica",
        lastName: "Taylor",
        dateOfBirth: 1975,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "Spanish",
          fluent: "English",
          intermediate: "French"
        }
      },

      {
        firstName: "Maurice",
        lastName: "Edelson",
        dateOfBirth: 1992,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "English",
          fluent: "Spanish",
        }
      },

      {
        firstName: "Kelly",
        lastName: "Lang",
        dateOfBirth: 1982,
        spokenLanguages: {
          native: "English",
          fluent: "German",
          intermediate: "Dutch"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #09c;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}


tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I explicitely didn't provide the OP the code for the table in my answer as they indicated that this was for an assignment and we shouldn't be doing peoples homework for them, but rather explaining and teaching the concepts. If this is for some kind of education, OP should be required to do atleast some part of the work...

Comment: @vigs welcome to SO. I read that too and you’re welcome to answer however you want ;) How do you know the HTML table wasn’t last week’s assignment and this week is how to destructure? You essentially did his work then. You also showed how to destructure the properties, which is more than what he asked and also possibly the cruft of the assignment. So now you’re picking and choosing what extra information you give him. Feel free to interpret the question however you wish, but also try to avoid the hypocrisy in the process.